# How to pass something to new page with javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm trying to pass something like var or list to new page.

So, I have two pages name `a.html` and `b.html`.

This is `a.html`,

```html
<html>
<head>
 <script language="Javascript">
  var aaa = 1;
  var bbb = [ 2, 3, 4 ];
  function newPage() {
   window.open("b.html");
  }
 </script>
</head>
<body>
 <input type="button" value="click me" onclick="newPage()">
</body>
</html>
```

and this is `b.html`.

```html
<html>
<head>
 <script language="Javascript">
 </script>
</head>
<body>
 
</body>
</html>
```

What I want to do is to use `var aaa` and `list bbb` in `b.html`.

I have searched to solve this problem, but I can't understand.

Can you give me an answer to solve this problem?

p.s. I don't know how to use jQuery.

Comment: Use query parameters or `sessionStorage`

Comment: If you want to open a new tab/window you can pass values in the URL. `b.html?query=queryvalue`

Comment: @CertainPerformance is a query parameter something in the URL like *b.html?name=jack&leet=true*?

Comment: @JackBashford Yep, like that (of course, would have to serialize/deserialize objects properly)

Comment: You can store your variables in `localStorage` and access them later from any other page

Comment: @Ahmad What's `localStorange`? How can I use it?

Comment: And I edited my question.(I can't use jQuery)

Comment: In `a.html` you can use `window.open("b.html?a="+aaa+"&b="+bbb);` and in `b.html` you can use `window.location.search` to get the values from the URL.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

One way to share data between pages in javascript is to use [`localStorage.setItem()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Storage/LocalStorage) and [`localStorage.getItem()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Storage/getItem).

In page `a.html`:

```
var aaa = 1;
var bbb = [ 2, 3, 4 ];
localStorage.setItem("aaa",aaa);  // store that value
localStorage.setItem("bbb",bbb);
```

And in page `b.html`:

```
var aaa = localStorage.getItem("aaa");   // read that value back.
var bbb = localStorage.getItem("bbb");
```

You can store variables with a key string. This key string can literaly be any valid string.

```
localStorage.setItem("my_data",aaa);
localStorage.setItem("email","any@email.com");
localStorage.setItem("cat1Lives",7);
```

but you will have to read them again using the same key that was used to set them.

```
var data = localStorage.getItem("my_data");
var email = localStorage.getItem("email");
var cat = localStorage.getItem("cat1Lives");
```

Comment: Thank you very much. It was really easy! You helped me a lot :)

Comment: I did. But I have a question. There's `localStorage.setItem("aaa", aaa);`. And what is first `"aaa"` and second `aaa`? And what's different between them?

Comment: @HoseongJeon the first `"aaa"` is the name of your variable. It can be anything. As long as you can remember to pull it out of the storage later. I just used the same variable names in your question.

Comment: @HoseongJeon you could say `localStorage.setItem("my data",aaa);`

Comment: Oh, then you mean string inside `" "`(like `"my data"`) is variable's name which is used in `getItem()`, and string without `" "`(like aaa) is the real variable's name which is used in a.html?

Comment: @HoseongJeon I updated my answer and included more details on how `localStorage` works. Hope that answers your queries. If not, please let me know

Comment: Now I can understand everything. Thank you very much :)

Answer (score 4):

You can't directly share variables between pages, but there're a few options for moving the information around:

- include query parameters in the url (i.e., instead of navigating to `b.html`, navigate to `b.html?param=value`) and parse them out of `document.location`
- set a cookie (may not work for local files, I've never tried it)
- look into HTML5 local storage options, there're a handful, but again I'm not sure how well they'd work for local files, if that's relevant

Comment: Thank you for your answer. But can you tell me in details about query parameters? Cause I don't know how to use jQuery.

Comment: Can you tell me with examples?

Comment: You don't need to use jQuery to access query parameters anyway.